# Background color working in HTML DOM but not in <style>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to set the background color of an `h2` in `<style>` so that it can have an `h2:hover` as well. Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <h1>Services</h1>
    <div v-for="service in services">
      <h2>Service: {{ service.id }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
h2 {
  background: darkseagreen;
  color: white;
}
h2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: mediumseagreen;
}
</style>
```

Problem is that the `h2 background` stays at its default color while everything else works perfectly (the text color is white on load, and when I hover over the headline, the cursor and background color both change). When I specify the color in the DOM, however,

```
<h2 style='background:darkseagreen' >Service: {{ service.id }}</h2>
```

it suddenly works just fine.

I don't want to set the style in the DOM, though, because I also would like to keep the `h2:hover` functionality.

What is wrong? Why can't I set the background color in `<style>`?

Comment: what kind of structure is this? why the template tag? what is the final HTML/CSS?

Comment: May be another css override your style. Make it have higher priority by using !important in the end of background attribute.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I didn't realise the `<template>` tag was overriding the background color. Adding `background: darkseagreen!important;` works, and though maybe not advised it is fine with me.